# How to make sure dropdown model loads after dropdown options load completes without breaking async nature of code in angular 9

Tags: angular, rxjs, primeng-dropdowns

I have primeng dropdown and two service calls, one making calls to get dropdown options and one to get model binding data. Once I saved the selected value and reload the page, occasionally selected value is not showing. I believe this because of the async nature of the service calls. I guess the model value service call is completed before loading all the dropdown options.

```
ngOnInit {
   this.drpOption = this.ddOptionSrv.getDrpOption();

   this.ddValueSrv.getDrpModelVal().subscribe(data => {
         this.drValue = data
   })
}
```

template code:

```
<p-dropdown [options]="drpOption | async" [(ngModel)]="drValue"></p-dropdown>
```

How do I make sure dropdown model value loads after dropdown options loads without moving the model service all inside the subscribed method of options call(maintaining the async nature)?

Answer (score 1):

I think you could try this:

```js
this.drpOption$ = this.ddOptionSrv.getDrpOption().pipe(share())

this.drValue$ = this.drpOption$.pipe(
  switchMapTo(this.ddValueSrv.getDrpModelVal()),
)
```

```html
<p-dropdown [options]="drpOption | async" [(ngModel)]="drValue | async"></p-dropdown>
```

By using `share()`, we're adding a `Subject` between the data producer(the service that provides the options) and the data consumers(the 2 subscribers from `| async`). With this, `ddOptionSrv.getDrpOption()` will be called only **once** and the returned value will be sent to the subscriber from `drpOption | async` and the subscriber from `drValue | async"`.

And with this you can be sure that the model value loads after options.

Answer (score 0):

One possible solution is to use [`combineLatest`](https://www.learnrxjs.io/learn-rxjs/operators/combination/combinelatest), let's look at a simpler example (imports omitted):

```js
@Component({
  selector: "my-app",
  templateUrl: "./app.component.html",
  styleUrls: ["./app.component.css"]
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
  data$: Observable<[number, number]>;

  private first$: Observable<number> = interval(1000);
  private second$: Observable<number> = interval(2000);

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.data$ = combineLatest([this.first$, this.second$]);
  }
}
```

and the template would be:

```html
<ng-container *ngIf="data$ | async as data">
    <div>first$ = {{ data[0] }}</div>
    <div>second$ = {{ data[1] }}</div>
</ng-container>
```

This way, the `async | data$` would wait for the first emission from both Observables, and on each emit, emits the latest values from each.

In addition, if both Observables emit only once, use [`forkJoin`](https://www.learnrxjs.io/learn-rxjs/operators/combination/forkjoin) instead of `combineLatest`.
You can run the demo in [this stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-3hsmmr?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html)

Comment: In my case it is two different data type from two different data source. All I am trying to do is run second data source after first completes or at least call again after first completes without breaking async.